# Why Epoch showing the same accuracy?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to build IDS intrusion detection system and trying to predict the label if it is benign or DDos. But I get the same accuracy along epochs.

Code:

```
        from tensorflow import keras
    import numpy as np
    import datetime
    import time
    from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
    from keras.models import Sequential
    from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
    from keras import callbacks
    x=pd.DataFrame(X)
    x = x.values
    sample = x.shape[0]
    features = x.shape[1]
    #Train: convert 2D to 3D for input RNN
    x_train = np.reshape(x,(sample,features,1)) #shape  = (125973, 18, 1)
    #Test: convert 2D to 3D for input RNN
    x_test=pd.DataFrame(X_test)
    x_test = x_test.values
    x_test = np.reshape(x_test,(x_test.shape[0],x_test.shape[1],1))
Model = keras.Sequential([

        keras.layers.LSTM(80,input_shape=(features,x_train.shape[2]),
                          activation='sigmoid',recurrent_activation='hard_sigmoid'),
        keras.layers.Dense(1,activation="softmax")
    ])

Model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',loss='mse', metrics=['accuracy'])

#Training the model

Model.fit(x_train, y, epochs=10, batch_size= 32) 
Model.summary()

# Final evaluation of the model
scores = Model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print('/n')
print("Accuracy: %.2f%%" % (scores[1]*100))



Epoch 1/10
1074/1074 [==============================] - 92s 83ms/step - loss: 0.4180 - accuracy: 0.5820
Epoch 2/10
1074/1074 [==============================] - 79s 74ms/step - loss: 0.4180 - accuracy: 0.5820
Epoch 3/10
1074/1074 [==============================] - 81s 76ms/step - loss: 0.4180 - accuracy: 0.5820
```

What is the solution?

Comment: You are mixing imports between tf.keras and keras, which is not a good idea

Comment: So Do I use one only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `"softmax"` activation with 1 neuron always outputs 1. Your neuron can't adjust its output to reduce loss; it mathematically can only return 1.

Comment: What is the recommended adjustment ?

Comment: You should look into the loss functions, metrics, and activation functions for your task. Seems like it's a 2 category problem, and so `"sigmoid"` activation would work, with `"binary_crossentropy"` as loss